# Azure Data Factory: How do I delete subfolders after a copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am performing a copy activity that copies all the contents of a particular folder including sub folders into a destination folder. I want to be able to delete all the copied files and their associated sub folders after copying them. the 'Delete files after completion' option only deletes files and not subfolders, if I try using delete activity it does not allow me.

Say I have MainFolder which contain subfolder1 and subfolder2 with files inside them.
I want to copy subfolder1 and subfolder2 with their respective contents
I want to delete subfulder1 and subfolder2 after copying them so that I will have an empty MainFolder

Please help

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG4hj.png)
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw3wP.png)

Comment: What is it mean by does not allow, can you provide the error if you got any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete subfolders under the root folder in an ADLS account, you can follow the procedure below:

Upon the success of the copy activity, add a Get Metadata activity with the child items field using the Mainfolder dataset. It will display the list of subfolders as shown below:

[image]

Add a Foreach activity to the Get Metadata activity with enabled sequential and `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` items. Inside the Foreach activity, add a Delete activity using a dataset with the dataset parameter `path` for the directory to delete activity with the dynamic value `@concat('Mainfolder/',item().name)` as shown below:

[image]

Debug the pipeline, and it will debug successfully without any errors, deleting the subfolders in the main folder as shown below:

[image]

Before Pipeline debug:

[image]

After pipeline debug:

[image]

**Note:** If your folder is in blob storage, it will delete the main folder itself because blob storage does not support empty folders.